# Is "If it had been for you" grammatical?

Tags: verbs

I came across the following sentence:

- "I acted as if it had been for you." (V. Hugo)

Since "if it had been for you/we/they" don't have results after searching on Google Search (site:.us), can someone clarify if it is grammatical?

Could we rewrite the sentence as follow without change in meaning?

- "I acted as if I had been you."

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it is grammatical. The context in which the sentence appears is helpful:

> Farewell, my dear friend; I received a letter from M. de la Mertiniere lately, inclosing a few lines from you; pray thank him for it. I have done all I could for his ode, but he owes me no thanks for this; **I acted as if it had been for you.** Farewell; thank you again for your verses; I like them, they convince me much more strongly of your friendship than of my own talents.

The meaning here is roughly the same as,

> I pretended that I was doing it for your benefit.

The suggested rewrite would not preserve the meaning.

Comment: +1, but who is 'it'. Is it the 'acting'?

Comment: @RégisRoux The 'it' refers to the act of doing "all he could" for M. de la Meriniere's ode. Presumably, Victor Hugo gave writing advice to Meriniere, and is explaining to a mutual friend (to whom he is writing the letter) that giving the advice was not a burden, because he and the letter's recipient are such dear friends.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Cameron is correct, about this construction in this context.

However, you have to distinguish this construction from the [NPI](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/NPIs.pdf) idioms

- *if it hadn't been for **X**...*
- *if it weren't for **X**...*

These refer to a hypothetical outcome that has been averted by **X**, they require both negation and *if*, and they are brilliantly ungrammatical without them.

- *If it hadn't been/weren't for him, I'd be dead now.*
- **If/Since it had been/has been/was for him, I'd be/I'm alive now.*

(An asterisk before a sentence indicates an ungrammatical, hypothetical example in linguistics.)